# Java 8 - collecting into a map from a list of objects with nested list

Tags: java, collections, java-8, nested, java-stream

I have a class with nested static class like:

```
public class User {
    private final Long userId;
    private final List<UserData> userData;

    {...}

    @Getter
    public static class UserData {
        private final Long customerId;
        private final String customerName;

    {...}
    }
}
```

Then I have a `List<User> users`.
I would like to map `users` to `Map<User.userId, UserData.customerId>`.

So the map would look like this:
1. userId1, customerId1
2. userId1, customerId2
3. userId1, customerId3
4. userId2, customerId4
5. userId2, customerId5
6. userId3, customerId6
etc.

Any chance to do that via Java 8 streams? I've tried flatmapping the nested list, but having a problem with collecting the results.

Comment: Recall: A map cannot have duplicate keys!

Comment: `but having a problem with collecting the results.` What problem?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a `Map<User.userId, List<UserData.customerId>>` you can use this:

```
 Map<Long, List<Long>> result = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        User::getUserId,
        u -> u.getUserData().stream()
            .map(UserData::getCustomerId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Comment: @GhostCat I first perceived it as a good question so I began writing, but now I have to admit. I just broke my first rule on SO: *Don't answer low quality questions*. Well, I already posted it, so I may aswell leave it here

Comment: What's `map` here but?

Comment: I believe there is a need for a `mergeFunction` with the expected output to delivered result data structure type change. Another alternative with Java9+, would be `Map<Long, List<Long>> out = users.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getUserId,
                        Collectors.flatMapping(a -> a.getUserData().stream().map(User.UserData::getCustomerId),
                                Collectors.toList())));`